# Can you make an element wrap around another one with CSS grid?

Tags: css, grid-layout

I am  trying to create the following layout :

[image: layout]

Note that it is important here that the green zone is a single element as I would like to fill it with text. I am planning to use the CSS columns property to display text in 4 columns (left to right) as shown by the arrows.

I thought I might be able to achieve this using CSS grid layout, this is what I've tried so far :

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
</div>

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a b b a"
    "a a a a";
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: a;
  background-color: green;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: b;
  background-color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m5cvL99e/

Is this possible using CSS grid layout or some other properties ?

Comment: You want the text in green box to float around the red box left and right? But how should the text float? You need to explain this. Look maybe at this for inspiration: https://css-tricks.com/examples/FloatBoth/ - It is maybe not exactly what you want, but maybe reasonable.

Comment: I've modified the image and added some text to explain how I would like the text to flow. Your link is pretty close to what I want to achieve but uses two separate elements for the text - I would like to use only one as it will be filled in dynamically.

Comment: If you are planing to use grid take a look at browser support http://caniuse.com/#search=grid

Comment: I'm aware of the limited browser support for grid layout - this is for an experiment not a real website.